# 3-column template fixed problems

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position, fixed

I'm trying to make a 3-column template. I want to "position: fixed" sidebars. But there is a problem. You can understand the problem when you click on the jsfiddle link. please help me.

Here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cs8x176t/)

Codes:

```css
.a {
  background: #607d8b;
  padding: 15px;
}

.b {
  background: #03a9f4;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
}

.c {
  background: #673ab7;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.d {
  background: #4caf50;
  float: right;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">fixed and floating left</div>
  <div class="c">center<div style="height:500px"></div></div>
  <div class="d">fixed and floating right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Weclome to SO. Please describe the problem directly in the question. Also make sure you read the help before posting on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

```css
.a {
  background: #607d8b;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.b {
  background: #03a9f4;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
}

.c {
  background: #673ab7;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.d {
  background: #4caf50;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">fixed and floating left</div>
  <div class="c">center<div style="height:500px"></div></div>
  <div class="d">fixed and floating right</div>
</div>
```

Try to change like this.

```
.a {
  background: #607d8b;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.d {
  background: #4caf50;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

When you use `position: fixed`, you should use with `top`,`bottom`,`left`,`right`.

Comment: problem is: https://image.prntscr.com/image/Uf62Tg-eRQmN9nN-fKvD-g.png @young-kyun-jin

Comment: Why don't use `absolute position`? like `top`, `bottom`

Comment: I edited. you should learn how to use `position: fixed` and `position: absolute`, `position: relative`. It's important things and helpful to you.

Comment: the problem still continues > [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cs8x176t/1/)

Comment: Try to change `right: 10px` => `left: 220px` from `.d`class

Comment: there is no other way?

Comment: In this code? YES.  But I think you have to remake your code. If you want to use `position:fixed`, you should know how to use it.